# How to add to a casted list in a HashMap?

Tags: java, casting, dplyr

I have a `Map<String, Object>`, and one of the values is a `List<String>`. Currently, I have:

```
if (!data.containsKey(myVar)) {
  List<String> emp = new ArrayList();
  data.put(myVar, emp); // myVar is a String
} else {
  data.get(myVar).add(otherVar); // "add" gives an error; otherVar is a String
}
```

My current solution is to do

```
} else {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<String> vals = (List<String>) data.get(myVar);
  vals.add(otherVar);
  data.put(myVar, vals);
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: What are myvar, othervar, mykey ?

Comment: "*one of the values is a List<String>*": what is (are) the type(s) of the other values?

Comment: Shorter way: `((List<String>) data.get(myVar)).add(otherVar);`

Comment: Shorter way for `put` too: `data.put(myVar, new ArrayList<String>());`

Comment: Better way: Rethink having a `Map` of varying value types.

Comment: @azro updated. thanks for the catch!

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez The Map either has strings or lists as it's values

Comment: What prevents you to always use a list of strings as values of the map? The fact that your map holds two different data types and that you need to characterize the type of the values with `Object` as a type parameter is the sign of a broken design - I would start to question this design/requirement first rather than trying to work around the problem which derives from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can change `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, List<String>>`, there's no better solution. You need a cast. You can of course add `instanceof` checks and extract it to a helper method, but in the end you need a cast.

One thing though: you don't need to do another `put` into the map — `vals.add(otherVar)` modifies the `List` which is already in the map, it doesn't return a new list instance.

---

Regarding a one-liner (casting to `List<String>` and doing `add` in the same line) — this isn't very good since then you would either have to tolerate the "unchecked cast" compiler warning, or you would have to put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` at the *method* level, which could suppress other warnings of this type within the method.

---

**EDIT**

> The Map either has strings or lists as it's values

In this case you may consider changing the data structure to `Map<String, List<String>>`. A list consisting of a single element is perfectly valid :)

Then the code gets really simple. In Java 8 it's a one-liner:

```
data.computeIfAbsent(myVar, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(otherVar);
```